# PHP - file_put_contents file manipulation

Tags: php, security, exploit, file-put-contents, file-manipulation

I'm trying to write a PHP file on a server and to bypass the extension in the end.

This is the PHP file - 1.php:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("folder\\".$GET['file'].".PNG",$_GET['content']);
?>
```

I'm trying to bypass the PNG extension and to write a PHP file.
like this:

```
1.php?file=attack.php%00&content=blabla
```

but it's not working

I tried:

```
Null char (%00,%u0000)

Long filename

CRLF chars

space char

?,&,|,>,<,(,),{,},[,],\,!,~,:,; chars

backspace char

../
```

php protocol

```
php://filter/write=convert.base64-decode/resource=1.php
```

(will not work because the folder in the begging)

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several fundamental problems here;

- This code is **very** unsafe, I could set get as `../../1.php` and overwrite this file to do whatever I want.  It appears that you're doing some security testing however, so I guess that may be the problem
- php is not a protocal, it's a language so `php://anything` should not work.
- `folder\\` doesn't make sense, what is this supposed to be/do?

That said though, for educational purposes prepending `../../` should allow you to escape out of the `folder/` directory.

For example if this is in `/home/Zak/mytest/` with the expectation of a directory within that called `folder` designated to store these PNG files, then a `file` of `../../zak_homedir` should put a file at `/home/Zak/zak_homedir.PNG` due to relative path resolution.

Comment: 1) Yes you esacpe the directory by doing ..\..\ but it's will save it as png file ../../1.php.png because the ".PNG" in the end
2) php protocol read here: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php
3) the file will write to the directory "folder"

Comment: Ah, my apologies; I was assuming another directory called "filter" after the `folder\\` directory mentioned above.